# ¿Cómo agregar imágenes o sonidos a directorio de salida cuando se compila proyecto .NET?

Tags: linux, .net

Estoy creando un proyecto con .NET v6.0.401 en Ubuntu 20.04 y uso Visual Studio Code.
Tengo una carpeta con recursos (imágenes y sonidos) que uso en el programa, para ello **es necesario que los archivos se copien en el directorio de salida `bin/Debug/net6.0/`**. 
He visto tutoriales de cómo hacer que los archivos se copien en la carpeta donde aparecen los binarios pero es con Visual Studio sobre Windows.

Mi proyecto se compone de:

1. Solución.

   - Proyecto 1 de tipo consola que llama clases contenidas en Proyecto 2.
   - Proyecto 2 (classlib) en el que se encuentran los recursos (imágenes y sonidos) y clases.

Cree la solución y los dos proyectos desde la terminal usando `dotnet` y ya agregé las referencias necesarias entre proyectos y funciona correctamente.
Ahora bien, ¿existe algún comando para hacer que la carpeta con archivos se copie al directorio de salida al compilar? ¿Algún detalle que deba saber?
Si ejecuto `dotnet --info` obtengo:

```
SDK DE .NET:
 Version:   6.0.401
 Commit:    0906eae6f8

Entorno de tiempo de ejecución:
 OS Name:     ubuntu
 OS Version:  20.04
 OS Platform: Linux
 RID:         ubuntu.20.04-x64
 Base Path:   /usr/share/dotnet/sdk/6.0.401/

global.json file:
  Not found

Host:
  Version:      6.0.9
  Architecture: x64
  Commit:       163a63591c

.NET SDKs installed:
  6.0.401 [/usr/share/dotnet/sdk]

.NET runtimes installed:
  Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 6.0.9 [/usr/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 6.0.9 [/usr/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App]

Download .NET:
  https://aka.ms/dotnet-download

Learn about .NET Runtimes and SDKs:
  https://aka.ms/dotnet/runtimes-sdk-info
```

Comment: Podes agregar como haces el build? seguro tiene algun flag que le diga que carpetas o archivos agregar...

Comment: @gbianchi para compilar el proyecto primero me cambio al directorio donde se encuentra el archivo .csproj y uso el comando dotnet build
Así compila el proyecto y sus referencias.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La solución fue agregar el siguiente código al archivo .csproj por cada imagen o sonido a incluir:

```
  <ItemGroup>
  <None Update="img/img.png">
  <CopyToOutputDirectory>Always</CopyToOutputDirectory>
  </None>
  </ItemGroup>
```

Comment: Si no me equivoco puedes usar comodines. Por ejemplo, con `img/*.png` copias todos los archivos .png de la carpeta `img`.

Comment: @Mateo ya lo he probado y funciona con el comodín. Gracias.