# Rutas de archivos entre proyectos .NET

Tags: linux, .net, vscode

Tengo un proyecto que tiene como estructura:

1. Solución `solution`

   - Proyecto de tipo consola (`console`)
   - Librería de clases (`classlib`)

En la librería de clases se encuentra una carpeta con sonidos que uso desde el proyecto tipo consola.
Con la siguiente ruta debería funcionar:

```
AudioFileReader audioFile = new AudioFileReader("Resources/sound.wav");
```

Esta línea se encuentra en un método de una clase contenida en `classlib` la cual instancio correctamente en `console`, sin embargo, al ejecutar lanza la excepción:

```
Unhandled exception. System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException: Could not find a part of the path '~/solution/console/Resources/sound.wav'
```

#### La compilación se realiza de manera correcta pero el programa, por alguna razón busca el sonido en la carpeta del proyecto de tipo consola y no en la librería de clases.

Como extra, si uso:

```
AudioFileReader audioFile = new AudioFileReader("../classlib/Resources/sound.wav");
```

Aparentemente funciona (manda otra excepción no relacionada a la ubicación del archivo sino a la falta de una dll para reproducir audio).
**Uso Ubuntu, net6.0 y Visual Studio Code, cree la solución con la terminal y el comando dotnet. Además se agregaron las referencias entre proyectos.**

El archivo `.sln` contiene lo siguiente:

```
Microsoft Visual Studio Solution File, Format Version 12.00
# Visual Studio Version 17
VisualStudioVersion = 17.0.31903.59
MinimumVisualStudioVersion = 10.0.40219.1
Global
    GlobalSection(SolutionConfigurationPlatforms) = preSolution
        Debug|Any CPU = Debug|Any CPU
        Release|Any CPU = Release|Any CPU
    EndGlobalSection
    GlobalSection(SolutionProperties) = preSolution
        HideSolutionNode = FALSE
    EndGlobalSection
EndGlobal
```

Mas detalles en [¿Cómo agregar imágenes o sonidos a directorio de salida cuando se compila proyecto .NET?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/559733/78188)

Comment: Según recuerdo, la ruta es relativa es relativa a la carpeta desde donde se llama a la aplicación

Comment: @Yussef con la ruta relativa funciona pero el tutorial que he visto lo hace como en la primera opción que muestro y sí funciona. Como he creado todo manualmente con el comando dotnet no sé si he ignorado hacer algo.